# Programatically added context menus to Word VSTO add-in in a loop causing problems

Tags: c#, vsto, word-addins

I followed the steps of creating a VSTO addin from these two articles:

1. [Create your first VSTO Add-in for Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-word?view=vs-2019)
2. [Create a custom tab by using the Ribbon Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-the-ribbon-designer?view=vs-2019)

I didn't use Ribbon Xml, rather, I used the Visual Designer (and added ribbon event handler code simply by double clicking the event handler property in the designer - which added the code to the *.designer.cs file instead of Ribbon_Load event like article suggested).

Maybe I have to start over and use Xml instead, but I'm trying to add a menu item to various context menus in Word where I want one of my ribbon functions available.

Based on [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dda9c1c7-d5d4-4f94-b60a-070f99becb6f/excel-addin-commandbarbutton-click-event-fires-only-the-first-time?forum=vsto), I created a `List<Office.CommandBarButton> contextMenus = new List<Office.CommandBarButton>();` to hold a reference to each button I create so that subsequent clicks worked after the initial run.

```
private void insertDocGenContext_Click( Office.CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault )
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine( "Click triggered on " + Ctrl.accName );
    var ribbon = Globals.Ribbons.GetRibbon<Ribbon>();
    ribbon.configInsert_Click( null, null );
}

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var targetMenus = new[] { "Form Fields", "Text", "Headings", "Fields", "Lists", "Table Lists", "Table Cells", "Table Text", "Table Headings" };
    var commandBars =
        Application.CommandBars.OfType<Office.CommandBar>()
            .Where( cb => cb.Position == Office.MsoBarPosition.msoBarPopup && targetMenus.Contains( cb.Name ) )
            .ToArray();

    foreach ( var cb in commandBars )
    {
        // I've set 'true' for temporary when I add, but they still seem to be there when I restart word
        var commandsToRemove =
            cb.Controls.OfType<Office.CommandBarButton>().Where( c => c.Tag == "RBLe.InsertDocGen" ).ToArray();

        foreach ( var r in commandsToRemove )
        {
            r.Delete( false );
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine( "Deleted RBLe.InsertDocGen from " + cb.Name );
        }

        var button = (Office.CommandBarButton)cb.Controls.Add( Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, missing, missing, missing, true );

        button.BeginGroup = true;
        button.Caption = "Insert/Edit DocGen Field";
        button.Tag = "RBLe.InsertDocGen";
        button.accName = button.Tag + "." + cb.Name;

        button.Click += insertDocGenContext_Click;

        contextMenus.Add( button );

        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine( "Added RBLe.InsertDocGen to " + cb.Name );
    }
}
```

I have two problems/questions:

1. After adding my buttons, when I click on one of them, the
   `insertDocGenContext_Click` handler fires 14x (once for each button
   I've created after looping my desired `targetMenus`), and every time
   the `Ctrl.accName` is the same, making me think somehow I'm getting
   an existing reference to a button and adding the event handler over
   and over?
2. Even though I set `temporary` to `true` in my call to
   `cb.Commands.Add()`, they still appear to be there when I restart
   Word/Visual Studio, thus needing my delete loop.

Answer (score 0):

`CommandBars` were deprecated. You need to use the Fluent UI to customize context menus in Office applications. Read more about that in the [Customizing Context Menus in Office 2010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee691832(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.

Comment: So no way to do this programatically?  I have to start over and use an Xml file to describe?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issues:

For the first issue, I was setting the `Tag` property the same on all items, and either Word (or the VSTO framework) was then triggering the event handler for all buttons with the same `Tag`.  [This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61454983/166231) helped point me in the correct direction with the 'yourTagLabelplusaDiffNumber' comment.

For the second issue, I didn't really solve it, but I understand it. This article on [Temporary CommandBars](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/ribbon/code-snippets-temporary-commandbars.htm) and [CustomizationContext in Word addin: No document is open](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8ef10195-543f-4bba-b4fb-ca35b6440d0d/customizationcontext-in-word-addin-no-document-is-open?forum=vsto) (which has a comment from Eugene as well) explained it.  I didn't go the route of installing my own template to have a separate `CustomizationContext`, but instead just settled on removing all my added menus during the `Startup` and `Shutdown` events of my add-in.

I read the article (and associated series) from Eugene, and I'm not convinced I wouldn't have had the same issues even after using the Xml FluentUI.  I've written an Excel Add-in using the FluentUI so I am familiar with it and probably just got lucky by not having the same `Tag` on any of the buttons therefore not experiencing the problem.